# Do filters complementive to a given filter form a complete lattice?

Tags: lattice-theory, filters

Really I should first ask this question here on MathOverflow and only then [post it as an open problem](http://garden.irmacs.sfu.ca/?q=op/do_filters_complementive_to_a_given_filter_form_a_complete_lattice) in Open Problem Garden and [propose it as a polymath problem](http://portonmath.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/proposal-conjecture-complementive-filters/). Indeed I did the reverse and now hope that for somebody my "open problem" may be simple.

Let $U$ is a set. A filter (on $U$) $\mathcal{F}$ is by definition a non-empty set of subsets of $U$ such that $A,B\in\mathcal{F} \Leftrightarrow A\cap B\in\mathcal{F}$. Note that unlike some other authors I do not require $\varnothing\notin\mathcal{F}$. I will denote $\mathscr{F}$ the lattice of all filters (on $U$) ordered by set inclusion.

Let $\mathcal{A}\in\mathscr{F}$ be some (fixed) filter. Let $D= \{ \mathcal{X}\in\mathscr{F} | \mathcal{X}\supseteq \mathcal{A} \}$. Obviously $D$ is a bounded lattice.

I will call complementive such filters $\mathcal{C}$ that:

1. $\mathcal{C}\in D$;
2. $\mathcal{C}$ is a complemented element of the lattice $D$.

**Conjecture** The set of complementive filters ordered by inclusion is a complete lattice.

Read also [my current progress on this problem](http://portonmath.wordpress.com/2009/11/02/exposition-complementive-filters/).

Comment: You haven't included the requirement that filters are closed upwards under superset.

Comment: Perhaps add the lattice tag? 

Comment: Does "complementive" or "complemented" here mean closed under taking complements as subsets of $U$? If so, then these "complementive filters" as you are calling them sound like the same things as Boolean subalgebras of the power set of $U$ (although I wouldn't call them filters unless you mean to include upward closure, which it sounds like you don't want to do). 

Comment: @Joel and Todd: Upward closure follows from Porton's assumption about intersections, because he has a biconditional there, not just the left-to-right implication.

Comment: Yes, Andreas. Also, I disagree with the votes to close---this is an interesting question.

Comment: @Todd, no. I've clearly said that it is about filters complemented as an element of the lattice $D$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The complementive filters ordered by inclusion form a lattice isomorphic to the quotient of the power set of $U$ modulo the filter $\mathcal A$.  So, for example, if $U=\omega$ and if $\mathcal A$ is the filter of cofinite sets, then the lattice of complementive filters would not be complete.

To establish the isomorphism, consider a complementive filter $\mathcal C$ and its complement $\mathcal C'$ in $D$.  The filter generated by $\mathcal C\cup\mathcal C'$ is the join in $D$, so it must be the top element, the improper filter of all subsets of $U$.  So there must be a set $Q\in\mathcal C$ whose complement $U-Q$ is in $\mathcal C'$.

I claim that $\mathcal A\cup\{Q\}$ generates $\mathcal C$.  To see this, suppose not, and consider some $Z\in\mathcal C$ that is not in the filter generated by $\mathcal A\cup\{Q\}$.  Then $Z\cup(U-Q)$ cannot be in $\mathcal A$ (because, if it were, then its intersection with $Q$ would be in the filter generated by $\mathcal A\cup\{Q\}$, but this intersection is included in $Z$, which is not in that filter).  But, since $Z\in\mathcal C$ and $U-Q\in\mathcal C'$, the union $Z\cup(U-Q)$ is in the intersection of these two filters, which is $\mathcal A$ (because they're complements in $D$).  This contradiction establishes the claim.

Thus, each complementive $\mathcal C$ in $D$ is generated by the fixed $\mathcal A$ plus one more set $Q$.  It is easy to check that the filter generated by  $\mathcal A\cup\{Q\}$ and the filter generated by $\mathcal A\cup\{R\}$ are equal if and only if $Q$ and $R$ represent the same element in the quotient Boolean algebra $\mathcal P(U)/\mathcal A$.  Better, the filter generated by $\mathcal A\cup\{Q\}$ is included in the one generated by $\mathcal A\cup\{R\}$ if and only if the element of $\mathcal P(U)/\mathcal A$ represented by $R$ is below (in the Boolean algebra) the one represented by $Q$.  Thus, the correspondence between $\mathcal C$ and ($Q$ modulo $\mathcal A$) is an order-reversing bijection between the lattice of complementive filters and the Boolean algebra $\mathcal P(U)/\mathcal A$.

Since a Boolean algebra and its dual order are isomorphic, this proves my description of the structure of the lattice of complementive filters.

Comment: What you mean by "modulo filter"? I don't know such a term.

Comment: The quotient of a Boolean algebra $B$ modulo a filter $F$ is obtained from $B$ by identifying two elements $x$ and $y$ iff there is $a\in F$ such that $x\wedge a=y\wedge a$.  This relation between $x$ and $y$ is a congruence relation (in the sense of universal algebra), so the quotient inherits from $B$ a Boolean algebra structure.

Comment: Why $\omega$ modulo filter of co-finite sets is not complete?

Comment: Partition $\omega$ into infinitely many infinite sets $A_n$; their images $[A_n]$ in the quotient have no supremum, for the following reason.  Given any upper bound $[X]$ (so, for each $n$, $X$ contains all but finitely many elements of $A_n$), choose, for each $n$, one element $z_n$ in $X\cap A_n$, and let `$Y=X-\{z_n:n\in\omega\}$`.  Then $[Y]$ is also an upper bound for the $[A_n]$'s and it is strictly below $[X]$ because $X-Y$ is infinite.  

Comment: @Andreas: It is expected that I will greatly simplify your proof using terminology which I define in http://www.mathematics21.org/binaries/filters.pdf

Indeed do you want me to acknowledge you in my publication?

Comment: @Andreas: I have a question: How you have succeed to solve the problem which I failed? Where you got the idea that these two lattices are isomorphic? How you understood that $\omega$ modulo the co-finite filter is not complete, even before you wrote a proof of this for me?

Maybe you may suggest some book from which is possible to borrow these ideas? I want to learn from you.

Comment: @Andreas: It seems you made a little error (seemingly not undetermining the entire proof). I think that $\mathcal{P}(U)/\mathcal{A}$ is not generally a boolean algebra, because my little attempt to prove that it is a boolean algebra failed. It is simply a lattice. I have not proved the opposite (that it is not a boolean algebra) however. Is it an error?

Comment: Oh, well it is a boolean algebra because it is isomorphic to the boolean lattice of complementive filters. Right?

Comment: I put online my updated article (http://www.mathematics21.org/binaries/filters.pdf) with this Andreas Blass' isomorphism and the counterexample. My proof is split into smaller steps and is simpler by the price of that it uses more advance terminology.